# How to use `std::unordered_map` in a thread-safe way?

Tags: c++, multithreading

#### What I have done

I had the idea to wrap `std::unordered_map`, and the to lock it for every
operation. And it looked something like this (I will just leave one operation
to not clutter the question):

```cpp
template<class Key, class T>
class thread_safe_unordered_map {
   public:
    T &operator[](const Key &key) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{m_mutex};
        return m_underlying[key];
    }

   private:
    std::unordered_map<Key, T> m_underlying;
    std::mutex                 m_mutex;
};
```

But then this crossed my mind, and now I dont know how to do it correctly.

Imagine this situation.

**Thread 1:** Calls operator[] to write
**Thread 2:** Calls operator[] to read from it

Both do their stuff. Now, because operator[] returns a reference, and they both
will act on the same reference, I think that this could still be a data race.
Is this right?

#### My idea now

Because of [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety):

> All const member functions can be called concurrently by different threads on
> the same container. In addition, the member functions begin(), end(),
> rbegin(), rend(), front(), back(), data(), find(), lower_bound(),
> upper_bound(), equal_range(), at(), and, except in associative containers,
> operator[], behave as const for the purposes of thread safety.

I have this question. Would it be correct to use `at()` on the threads, and the
thing that gets locked is the mapped value?

Comment: returning a non-const reference is the opposite of encapsulation. You are right that the lock does not help to protect concurrent reads and writes to the same memory resuling in a data race

Comment: Worse, that freshly fetched reference may become a dangling reference at any moment, without warning.  If lucky, you'll be able to do some forensic debugging on the impact crater to figure out what went awry.

Comment: Do you ever remove elements from the map in the multi-threaded region? If no, you should be ok. Once an element is inserted into an unordered map, its address should remain intact. Anyway, this approach would be inefficient. There are concurrent hash tables provided by external libraries, such as Intel TBB or Facebook Folly (IIRC). Also, as pointed to, updates of elements may result in data race.

Comment: Nope, none are deleted. Some are inserted at the start, and after that only one thread can modify the existing elements, and the rest only read from it. Thanks for the advice, I will look at the libraries you told me. @DanielLangr

Comment: Locking on each operation is generally not sufficient, since there are often times when you want to do multiple operations atomically (e.g. remove one entry and then insert a different entry, without any other threads having the possibility of seeing the interim-state between those two operations).  Therefore the better approach is to leave the locking out of the data structure and have it done at a higher level, where the code has a full understanding of what it is trying to accomplish atomically.

Comment: Java eliminated most of the thread safety on their containers like this because it made them run much slower, and didn't actually solve the real problem, which is that this is usually the wrong level for locking. The caller often wants to do _two_ calls in a lock, which this design doesn't help with at all.

Comment: Using `at()` makes no difference. Both `at()` and `operator[]` return a reference to the contents of the map. And the caller has access to the reference after the mutex is unlocked. This will result in a race with any other execution thread the might use `erase()` to remove the same key/value, and the subsequent access from the original execution thread will end up referencing a delete object, resulting undefined behavior. A complete thread-safe associative container will require a bit more work in order to achieve perfect thread safety in accessing its values.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik OP specified that elements are not removed/erased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, because operator[] returns a reference, and they both will act on the same reference, I think that this could still be a data race. Is this right?

This is right assuming `T` isn't a thread-safe type.

This isn't a data race in the operation of the container, but a data race in the use of the object of type `T`.

> I have this question. Would it be correct to use at() on the threads

If you only call the const qualified `at`, then you never get a non-const reference and thus cannot modify the value of any element. If you don't modify the values, then you don't have a data race.

If you use the non-const qualified `at`, then there is no difference in regards to the described data race.

P.S. You'll find that you wouldn't be able to have any synchronised non-const member functions because locking a mutex requires modification. You can get around that using `mutable`.